# When is $x \mapsto (1+|x|)^s$ square-integrable?

Tags: integration, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $s \in \mathbb{R}$.
I wonder what is a necessary and sufficient condition (in terms of $n$ and $s$) for

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} ((1 + \|x\|^2)^s)^2 \mathrm{d}x < \infty
$$
to hold. Here, $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean norm and the measure is the Lebesgue measure.

#### Context

I encountered the above question while reading a functional analysis textbook, and the integrability of the function (say, for $s < - n/4$) is used in a proof (in relation to Sobolev spaces).
So I was wondering (but could not find) if there is a systematic way to see when the above function is integrable.

Comment: The integrand is equal to $(1 + \| x \|^2)^{2s}$, right? Why does the integrand in the title and the one in the question differ? Since $\| \cdot \|^2$ is radially symmetric you could try to calculate this integral with polar coordinates,

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. The title says square-integrable, meaning that the function in the title is integrable after taking the square. The formula in the question is an explicit version of that. For the polar coordinates, thank you for the suggestion. I had actually tried that, but I could only get $s \leq -1/2$ as a sufficient condition (which does not include all of $s < -1/4$ for $n=1$). Let me update the question with what I have later.

Comment: I just noticed polar coordinate transform does not apply in $n=1$. Maybe this is why I was stuck. Thank you!